# Simple Where Clause has syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$entries = "INSERT INTO allowances (totalGrossPay) VALUES ('".$totalGrossPay."') WHERE (allowances.SSN = '".$SSN."')";
mysql_query ($entries) or die (mysql_error());
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (allowances.SSN = '300497654')'

Comment: U cannot use where in INSERT query, instead use UPDATE query

Comment: when u inserting means there is a complete new row so no means of using` where` condition, you must be updating a row. isn't it??

Answer (score 2):

What do you think should happen? `INSERT` is unconditional, no `WHERE` clause is required or even allowed.
What you really want is an `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 2):

Just do an update:

```
$entries = "UPDATE `allowances` SET `totalGrossPay` = '{$totalGrossPay}' WHERE `SSN` = '{$SSN}'";
mysql_query ($entries) or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to update a possibly existing record and otherwise insert the record, you can use the ON DUPLICATE KEY phrase of the INSERT statement to specify what happens if the record already exists.